# Datetime parse with jodatime for 19700101

Tags: jodatime

The result of `DateTime.parse("1970101", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd"));` is `1970-10-01 00:00:00` using jodatime.

I would like to convert it as `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: You've told it to parse the two digits after the year as the month by using `MM`; why would you expect it to do something different than exactly what you've said it should do? It appears that you've got some bad dates; a proper format would be the one you've indicated in your pattern. If you're not getting dates in that format, then you'll need to adjust your pattern to match what you're actually receiving. You're going to run into problems, though; how would you expect 1970121 to parse? As Jan 21st, or as Dec 1?

Comment: oops, there is a mistake in date string to be parse. thanks